# Switch logged in User Session Event capture from MFC Application in Windows

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC dialog based application.
Please anyone tell me how to capture the Switch user(windows logged in user) event from this MFC program.

I tried to capture the WM_QUERYENDSESSION from the Dialog's WindowProc function and I could able to capture the Shutdown, Restart and log off events using WM_QUERYENDSESSION.
But the "Switch user" event is not getting called with WM_QUERYENDSESSION.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/wm-wtssession-change) message.  Your application needs to call [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) to receive this message.